# Determine mouse click for all screen resolutions

Tags: php, javascript, geometry

I have some simple JavaScript that determines where a click happens within a browser here:

```
var clickDoc = (document.documentElement != undefined && document.documentElement.clientHeight != 0) ? document.documentElement : document.body;
var x = evt.clientX;
var y = evt.clientY;
var w = clickDoc.clientWidth != undefined ? clickDoc.clientWidth : window.innerWidth;
var h = clickDoc.clientHeight != undefined ? clickDoc.clientHeight : window.innerHeight;
var scrollx = window.pageXOffset == undefined ? clickDoc.scrollLeft : window.pageXOffset;
var scrolly = window.pageYOffset == undefined ? clickDoc.scrollTop : window.pageYOffset;

params = '&x=' + (x + scrollx) + '&y=' + (y + scrolly) + '&w=' + w + '&random=' + Date();
```

All of this data gets stored in a DB. Later I retrieve it and display where all the clicks happened on that page. This works fine if I do all my clicks in one resolution, and then display it back in the same resolution, but this, not the case. there can be large amounts of resolutions used.

In my test case, I was clicking on the screen with a screen resolution of 1260x1080. I retrieved all the data and displayed it in the same resolution. But when I use a different monitor (tried 1024x768 and 1920x1080. The marks shift to the incorrect spot.

My question is if I am storing the width and height of the client, and the x/y position of the click. If 3 different users all with different screen resolutions click on the same word, and a 4th user goes to view where all of those clicks happened, how can I plot the x/y position correctly to show that everyone clicked in the same space, no matter the resolution?

If this belongs in a better section, please let me know as well.

:::EDIT::: After applying brock's suggestions, I have attached two screenshots. I clicked on the word `If` at the beginning of each paragraph in different resolutions. When viewing in both those resolutions, the clicks that happened in the same resolution are directly on the word, when it's a higher or lower resolution, it shifts to the right or left, respectively.

http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/5682/1260x1080.png
http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/8950/1920x1080c.png%20

Comment: I don't know your requirements, but if that's possible for you, consider recording the path of the DOM element has been clicked rather than the mouse location.

Comment: From those screen shots, it LOOKS like the margins are different.  Post a whole screen shot or -- better still -- a link to the page.  I'll update my answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Additional issues to consider, the problem may not be perfectly solvable...

1. At different screen sizes, things like margins (for centered content) will be different.   Need to adjust to where *"screen size"* really becomes the `clientWidth` after compensating for changing margins.
2. Also, despite everything, a page just might render differently at different screen resolutions (plus whatever size the user has his browser window at).  If this causes lines to wrap differently, it will really throw off comparisons.

---

**Original Answer:**

> "if I am storing the width and height of the client, and the x/y position of the click. If 3 different users all with different screen resolutions click on the same word, and a 4th user goes to view where all of those clicks happened, how can I plot the x/y position correctly"

This should just be a simple scaling problem.

**Pseudo code:**
Given:

```
CapturedMousePosition   = {X and Y coordinates of logged machine, in pixels}    //-- EG  [42, 69]
CapturedScreenSize      = {width and height of logged machine, in pixels}       //-- EG  [1260, 1080]
TargetScreenSize        = {width and height of display machine, in pixels}      //-- EG  [1024, 768]
/*-- Note that client size and/or view-port size, are what we mean by "screen size" here.  
    This is because the browser will use some unknown fraction of the PC's display resolution.
*/
```

Then:

```
TargetMousePosition     = CapturedMousePosition * TargetScreenSize / CapturedScreenSize
EG: [42 * 1024 / 1260, 69 * 768 / 1080] -- Be sure to round to *nearest* integer.
```

Comment: I am close, but here is where it stands. I clicked on one word in 1260x1080. I clicked on another word in 1920x1080. Then I displayed the heatmap in 1260x1080. The viewing the clicks from the same resolution were fine, but the clicks from the higher resolution shifted to the right like 2 words (6 characters).

When viewing in 1920x1080, viewing the clicks made in the same resolution was fine, but the clicks made in a lower resolution shifted to the left about the same distance.

Comment: Updated original post with images of problem.

Comment: Is it possible that the pages are rendering slightly differently at the different screen sizes?  
It looks like you are using `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` instead of actual screen size -- so that shouldn't be it.  Post a link to the page or at least some screen shots.  6 characters is also suspiciously close to the width of a scrollbar.

Comment: Screenshots in original post now. I also switched the data I am logging to this. SHould I go back to clientHeight and clientWidth? I will try that.

    var x = evt.clientX;
    var y = evt.clientY;
    var width = screen.width;
    var height = screen.height;

Comment: I tried it with clientHeight and clientWidth, and everything went way out of whack. screen.width and screen.height seem to get me the closest.

Comment: I have modified the scaling for width, and it works 100% of the time now. (target innerWidth - captured innerWidth) / 2 + captured X. Posted this here for the off-chance someone else needs to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store the place in the document where the user clicked, what you are doing now should be ok.

If you need to store the place in the browser window (why?), you'd have to also store the browser resolution, or a normalized value based on the resolution.

Comment: I am creating a heatmap to monitor user activity which is working fine for recording and displaying in one resolution. Trying to make sure all the clicks are accurate.